# How to fix "cannot destructure property extends of undefined or null"

Tags: angular, gulp

I am setting up my nodeJS and the gulp command does crushes after starting the ts service. I want to be able to "gulp" and run "npm run compiler"

```html
PS D:\tfsGit\NewWorldProjects\Coruscant\Internal.UI\www> gulp
[11:59:36] Using gulpfile D:\tfsGit\NewWorldProjects\Coruscant\Internal.UI\www\gulpfile.js
[11:59:36] Starting 'scss'...
[11:59:36] Finished 'scss' after 9.42 ms
[11:59:36] Starting 'jsDependency'...
[11:59:36] Finished 'jsDependency' after 2.2 ms
[11:59:36] Starting 'ts'...
[11:59:36] 'ts' errored after 176 μs
[11:59:36] TypeError: Cannot destructure property `extends` of 'undefined' or 'null'.
```

Comment: use need check null before using

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for coming back to me! 
We have not introduce any null value. In fact we have a very different situation: where we have merge of AngularJS with Angular 2+. We used to perform gulp operation however, this behavior is only in a few machines,while it is working in others. We compared(and changed the version to ) the following with the working machines:
1. NPM version
2. node version
3. Gulp version
4. we compared the package.json file

However it does not work.

Interestingly, the gulp command works very well in another Virtual directory in my machine which is hosted under same IIS?